# Next.js build stuck compiling during docker build in bitbucket pipeline

Tags: node.js, docker, webpack, next.js, bitbucket-pipelines

I have converted a legacy react app from using Webpack 3 to use Next.js 12 and Webpack 5.

I am currently trying to deploy the project using Docker through bitbucket pipelines but when running `next build` it gets stuck on 'Creating an optimized production build' and eventually runs out of memory and the build fails.

I am using the same Dockerfile setup from next.js example and the docker build runs perfectly on my local machine with the same steps.

Has anyone experience a similar issue? No errors or anything are shown during `yarn install` or the build itself and I have outputStandalone set to true.

```
# Install dependencies only when needed

FROM node:16-alpine AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM node:16-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN yarn build

# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM node:16-alpine AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

# You only need to copy next.config.js if you are NOT using the default configuration
COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json

# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

Answer (score 3):

I did run into a similar issue with npm@7, due to https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2011 / https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/3208 , rant intended.

A workaround was to increase the docker service memory limits from bitbucket-pipelines.yml (default is 1024 MB)

```
definitions:
  services:
    docker:
      memory: 3072
```

or possibly even doubling the resources allocated for your step:

```
definitions:
  services:
    docker:
      memory: 7128
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        size: 2x
        services:
          - docker
        script:
          - docker build .
```

Beware that service resources are subtracted from those allocated for your step, so the step script would run on decreased memory.

Also remember you will be charged x2 for your `size: 2x` steps.

See https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/databases-and-service-containers/#Service-memory-limits

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. setting memory to 3072 solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to `out of memory` error, you could try setting Node memory before `yarn build`

```
ENV NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=4096
```